# Loops in integration

Tags: python, loops

I have an integral with periodic upper limit which depends on variable 'l'. Code looks like this:

```
Gamma = 0

for l in R:
    ln = l*MPC/4.1
    while l <= RS:
        for i in R:
            j = i*MPC/4.1
            Results = integrate.tplquad(J_nu, 0.0, np.pi, lambda theta: ln, lambda theta: sqrt(ln**2 + j**2 - 2 * ln * j * cos(theta)), lambda theta, s: nuth, lambda theta, s: np.inf)
            Gamma += Results[0]
```

For every value of l I need to calculate and then sum all integrals in every point along R (that's why I'm using another i-loop).

Is there any way to rewrite this code without multiple loops? Cause, Python needs very much time to compute this integral even for one value of l.

Comment: I believe that `integrate` function is from scipy, so maybe Ilya Khrykin is already aware of numpy

Comment: I'm using scipy and numpy indeed. And I'm not sure how to improve my code without loops. Well, of course, I'll check docs again.

Comment: the only idea I have is to pre-calculate `sqrt(ln**2 + j**2 - 2 * ln * j * cos(theta))` into an 3D array so that `your_array[ln][j][theta] = sqrt(ln**2 + j**2 - 2 * ln * j * cos(theta))` for every possible value of ln, j, theta (the last one have to be approximate, however). The array may be stored somewhere, like in a file and not recalculated every time. This will waste memory but may improve the overall performances a little bit.

Comment: But quad function can't deal with arrays. They don't output scalars

Comment: @furins
I'm trying to put values from array into quad function like this:
`
iterable = (x for x in R)
j = np.fromiter(iterable, np.float)

And have this: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: You might want to check out David Beazley's talks, Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers and A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency

Comment: @IlyaKhrykin I was thinking to a lambda function that retrieves data from the array

Comment: @furins anyway, It seems imposible to insert array values to the quad function.

Comment: I do not understand why, I mean `lambda theta, ln, j:yourarray[theta][ln][j]` whereas yourarray is an array accessible in the scope of integrate (in `globals` perhaps)